# JDBC SQLite path

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, netbeans

I'm testing my program which is already an .exe file to a different computer and I realized the path for my database is specified on my computer and the application will not be able to access the database. Is there a way to change this path so that I can test it on different computers? Here is my code for connecting to the database:

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class mysqlconn {

Connection conn=null;

 public static Connection ConnectDB(){
    try{
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        Connection conn= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\PAULO\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Admin_Laptopland\\laptop_land.sqlite");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Connection Established");
        return conn;
    }catch(Exception e){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);return null;}
  }
}
```

Comment: Use relative paths, ask the user to pick the database, use things like system property `user.home`, etc, etc, etc.

Comment: It's my first time using sqlite as my database in netbeans. How do I exactly do that?

Comment: Then there is  a nice [tutorial here for you](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-java/sqlite-jdbc-driver/)

Comment: Thank you but I still have a problem. I tried using this Connection conn= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:laptop_land.sqlite"); but then it just created a new database without any table. I want to connect the database that I already made. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

**Keep the db file on the same location of mysqlconn class, then use relative path for db string**, here is the code - change according to your needs :-

```
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class mysqlconn {

Connection conn = null;

public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connection Established");

    } catch (HeadlessException | ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

    }
}
```

}

here, filename of db file is test.db.

Comment: I'm trying to build the program and I'm running the jar file in the dist folder. The problem with that code is that it will just create a new db instead of getting the db I made. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Sorry, then this code will not help. because the db file (test.db) will itself packaged on executable( jar file in dist folder) file, and you can't connect to it. everytime a new db will be created. i am working on the problem...

Comment: It's ok. I fixed it by just replacing it with the one I made. Thank you